# Parallel Logistic Regression with GPU in Python (MinPy)

Tags: python, regression, mxnet

I just managed to set up an Anaconda Environment to run [this example](https://minpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/get-started/logistic_regression.html) from MinPy.

Now as I understand it, the parallelization is in the training and predicting part.

However, for my specific use case I want to go one level higher:
Since I have one very large data set that is split up in fairly small ones I want to do many multinomial regressions for each of the subsets.

Is there a way I can parallelize at this high of a level?
Since I am very new to the topic I simply do not know how to approach this problem.

Thanks in advance for any advice :)

Comment: If each individual subset uses all available CPUs in parallel, my understand is that there is no gain in running several of those subsets in parallel.